# What databases for Mac are directly supported by the FireMonkey framework in Delphi XE2?

Tags: database, macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Confronted with the task to develop a database application for a company working in a pure Mac environment, what are my options for a central database server to be used by a Delphi FMX application (except the obvious setting up a Windows or Linux box)?

Comment: I see that this might getting closed as off-topic. Well, in that case I would kindly ask to mention a more suitable place for this question.

Comment: I think this is very relevant to stack overflow. This is a question any developer using Firemonkey wants to know.

Comment: The only one I would trust to continue to be forever-available-on-mac-os-x would be Firebird, and MySQL because they are open source, and the only one I would make a long-term-bet on being able to continue to run on Mac Indefinitely is Firebird, because MySQL is now managed by Oracle.  Apple has a history of breaking backwards compatibility, orphaning binary only software routinely.  Thus, I would learn to build Firebird or MySQL from sources, if I was to support a Mac OS X DB server commercially.

Comment: I changed your title so it's more clearly on-topic for Stack Overflow. The features of the Firemonkey framework which is part of Delphi XE2 is distinctly on-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From http://www.embarcadero.com/products/firemonkey/more-connected:

> FireMonkey includes built-in component based access to MS SQL Server,
>   Oracle, IBM DB2, MySQL, Sybase, Informix, InterBase and Firebird
>   databases.

Oracle, MySQL and [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/) are available for Mac OS X - I did not check the others

Comment: I just noticed that my Interbase Developer Edition License may actually cover a version for Mac OS, too. That might be a good start - at least during development.

Comment: In order for DBExpress to connect to remote servers, you'll need at least the Enterprise version of Delphi.

Comment: Professional comes with ADO, and allows remote connections, but it's Windows only.

Comment: @Marcus, my RAD Studio is an Architect Edition, so I don't expect any missing pieces concerning database connection.

Answer (score 3):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deploying_dbExpress_Database_Applications

Only a few is listed in this article, so maybe they are all supported database at this moment.

libsqlinf.dylib

For applications connecting to Informix databases

libsqlora.dylib

For applications connecting to Oracle databases

libsqlasa.dylib

For applications connecting to Adaptive Server Anywhere databases

libsqlmys.dylib

For applications connecting to MySQL databases

libsqlfb.dylib

For applications connecting to Firebird databases

libsqlib.dylib

For applications connecting to Interbase databases

libmidas.dylib

Required by database applications that use client datasets

Comment: Do all these databases run on Mac OS servers?

Comment: Only Adaptive Server Anywhere is not supported on Mac (info from Sybase page), all others are supported on Mac (info from their vendors).

Comment: Oracle no longer supports MacOS servers. Probably because there are no real MacOS servers. Probably because you can't show tha apple logo when your server is buried in a datacenter, or worse runs in a VM...

Comment: @MadHatter, sounds reasonable ;) Meanwhile I was able to spot a Windows Server 2008 at the site. The people I first talked to weren't even aware of its existance - let alone that it is non-MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

**[MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/)** (It is a drop in replacement for MySql) and runs on the Mac and windows.

To connect to the database 
look at **Devart**'s [MyDac7.x](http://www.devart.com/mydac/history.html) it can connect to both MacOs and Windows

Comment: Well, that won't exactly fit into the "directly supported" section, but thanks for the hint.